# How to write a Jasmine test for printer function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to write a Jasmine test for the following print function:

```
  printContent( contentName: string ) {
    this._console.Information( `${this.codeName}.printContent: ${contentName}`)
    let printContents = document.getElementById( contentName ).innerHTML;
    const windowPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=925,height=1400,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
    windowPrint.document.write(printContents);
    windowPrint.document.close();
    windowPrint.focus();
    windowPrint.print();
    windowPrint.close();
  }
```

I am more than willing to change the function to be more testable.  This is my current test:

```
  it( 'printContent should open a window ...', fakeAsync( () => {
    spyOn( window, 'open' );
    sut.printContent( 'printContent' );
    expect( window.open ).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }) );
```

I am trying to get better code coverage.

Comment: What's the issue with your current test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make sure, `window.open()` returns a fully featured object since the `printContent` method under test uses properties and functions of `windowPrint`. Such an object is typically created with [`createSpyObj`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/jasmine.html#.createSpyObj).

```
var doc = jasmine.createSpyObj('document', ['write', 'close']);
var windowPrint = jasmine.createSpyObj('windowPrint', ['focus', 'print', 'close']);
windowPrint.document = doc; 
spyOn(window, 'open').and.returnValue(windowPrint);
```

Your amended unit test would then look as follows:

```
it( 'printContent should open a window ...', () => {

  // given
  var doc = jasmine.createSpyObj('document', ['write', 'close']);
  var windowPrint = jasmine.createSpyObj('windowPrint', ['focus', 'print', 'close']);
  windowPrint.document = doc;
  spyOn(window, 'open').and.returnValue(windowPrint);

  // when
  sut.printContent('printContent');

  // then
  expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=925,height=1400,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
  expect(doc.write).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
  expect(doc.close).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
  expect(windowPrint.focus).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
  expect(windowPrint.print).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
  expect(windowPrint.close).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
});
```